# Meaning of 玉ヒュン

Tags: meaning

What does 玉ヒュン mean?

It seems to have something to do with not experiencing fear of heights.

Context (posted on social media with a picture taken vertiginous height):

> 女だけど玉ヒュン！

Comment: こういうのググればすぐわかるよ。http://netyougo.com/slang/6828.html , http://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E3%82%BF%E3%83%9E%E3%83%92%E3%83%A5%E3%83%B3　etc

Comment: @Ash 高いとこから下見ると、ホントにキ○タ○って「ヒュン！」ってなるの？？

Comment: @Ash: I haven't found any definition in the first page of Google. Now that I search again, I can find your netyougo link (10th result) but it does not use the same spelling that's why I dismissed it.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul 「玉ヒュン　意味」で検索すればいろいろ出ますよ。

Comment: @Choko んー俺はならないな(笑)

Comment: @Ash: ありがとうございます、探し方の勉強になります！

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's kind of a crude term, so my answer here will be kind of crude, haha. I hope that's okay.

Ever heard a guy say, after seeing something like a video of somebody climbing a tall tower or something, that they felt fear? And that they felt it in their testicles?
玉ヒュン basically means that.

玉【たま】 here is a kanji-fied shortening of キンタマ, a colloquialism for 睾丸【こうがん】 (testicles). ヒュン is a sort of sound effect -- like something whizzing past you. To be honest, I'm not entirely sure how the ヒュン comes into effect here, but... it makes for something that's kind of fun to say, haha.

Basically what she's saying here is "[I got so scared that] I felt it in my balls, and I'm a woman!"